# A natural transpose linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If we have an isomorphism between vector spaces $f$, we can define an isomorphism whom representative matrix is the inverse of the $f$'s one in **every basis** (this is clearly $f^{-1}$). I was wondering if we could do the same also for transpose. I know for example that given a linear application $f:V \to W$, we can define $f^t:W^* \to V^*$ and this linear application's representative matrix is the transpose of $f$'s one but  **only in dual basis** .And I know that(in the real case) the adjoint's representative matrix is the transpose of the $f$'s one, but **only in orthonormal basis.**(That is practically the same of the last case, since a dual basis authomatically induces a scalar product $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=v_i^ *(v_j)$). Why do we need always some extra structure? Isn't there a more natural way to define this?

Comment: There is not a more natural way to do this because the is no natural isomorphism between $V$ and its dual space $V^*$.  Every identification of $f^t$ with a map from $W$ to $V$ requires a basis in some sense

Comment: You may find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194724/81360) interesting