# What does the dash mean in "$v \mapsto \langle v, -\rangle$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This quote is taken from a math.SE answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622695/816960):

> By the way, for Euclidean vector spaces, there *is* a canonical isomorphism, given by $V \to V^*$, $v \mapsto \langle v, -\rangle$.

What does the dash in this inner product mean? I've never seen this notation before? I assume it's some kind of placeholder, but for what I can't guess.

Comment: How do you write an element of $V^*$?

Comment: I would say it's the linear form associated to $vˆin an inner product space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element of $V^*$ is a linear map on $V$, ultimately a function $V \to F$. The notation $v \mapsto \langle v, -\rangle$ is a shorthand for $v \mapsto (w \mapsto \langle v, w \rangle)$, producing a member $w \mapsto \langle v, w \rangle$ of $V^*$ given a member $v$ of $V$.