# Dual space of finite dimensional space V has the same dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a simple proof showing that $\dim V^*=\dim V$? Where $V^*$ denotes the dual space of a finite dimensional space $V$?

Comment: You should be able to do it pretty directly by using the dual basis, although note that your statement is only true if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105490/isomorphisms-between-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-and-its-dual?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

Depends what you mean by "simple".  However, I think this proof is pretty straightforward:

---

Let $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$.  Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\} \subset V^*$ be defined so that
$$
f_i(v_j) = \begin{cases}
1 & i=j\\
0 & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
(This set is usually called the "dual basis" corresponding to our $v_i$s).
Now, show that theses functionals form a basis of $V^*$.  It would follow that $V^*$ is $n$-dimensional, as desired.

**Note:** Recall (or prove) that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformations such that $T_1(v_i) = T_2(v_i)$ for each $i$, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the same linear transformation.

Comment: Maybe you would please comment on Axler's proof (3.95) on page 101 of "Linear Algebra Done Right", 3rd ed. There he gives a one liner referring to a prior result: Dimension of $\mathcal L(V,W) =(\dim V)(\dim W)$

Comment: @Andrew that works too, but it assumes his prior result. In fact, we can go in the other direction too: one we have $\dim V^*$, there's a slick approach to the more general result on $L(V,W)$.